# Installed module is empty

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm tring to use `setuptools` for python3 code. My project structure:

```
./testSetup/
./testSetup/testSetup
./testSetup/testSetup/foo.py
./testSetup/Setup.py
```

**./testSetup/testSetup/foo.py** content:

```
def say_foo():
    print('foo')
```

**./testSetup/Setup.py** content:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import testSetup

setup(
    name='testSetup',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    author='Bastien Sevajol',
    author_email="testSetup@bux.fr",
    description='test',
    long_description='test test',
    include_package_data=False,
    url='http://bux.fr',
    # https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers.
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python",
    ]
)
```

When i `python Setup.py install` (with python3.4) in a virtual env:

```
python Setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating testSetup.egg-info
writing testSetup.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to testSetup.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to testSetup.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'testSetup.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'testSetup.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'testSetup.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

creating build
creating build/bdist.linux-i686
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying testSetup.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying testSetup.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying testSetup.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying testSetup.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating dist
creating 'dist/testSetup-0.0.1-py3.4.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-i686/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-i686/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing testSetup-0.0.1-py3.4.egg
Copying testSetup-0.0.1-py3.4.egg to /home/bux/.virtualenvs/testsynergine2/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Adding testSetup 0.0.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/bux/.virtualenvs/testsynergine2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/testSetup-0.0.1-py3.4.egg
Processing dependencies for testSetup==0.0.1
Finished processing dependencies for testSetup==0.0.1
```

I can see a warning saying `install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install`.

If i try to use my module:

```
python               
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from testSetup import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'foo'
>>> import testSetup
>>> dir(testSetup)
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

What's wrong in my Setup.py ?

Comment: The directory structure seems to be odd. You're saying you have `foo.py` in `testSetup/testSetup`? 'In testSetup directory'.

Comment: I edit the question, i malformed the dirs in question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have an `__init__.py` file in your `TestSetup/` directory (the file can be blank). Otherwise, nothing in that directory will be importable and `find_packages()` will never find it. You might want to [read](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#packages) [about](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-is-init-py-used-for.htm) [it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448271/).

```
./testSetup/
./testSetup/testSetup
./testSetup/testSetup/__init__.py
./testSetup/testSetup/foo.py
./testSetup/setup.py
```

Also note that `setup.py` should be all lowercase. While naming it `Setup.py` won't stop the script from working, it is not convention and may not be discovered by various tools.

Comment: With python3 ``__init__.py`` is useless no ?

Comment: @bux not according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#packages), which states: "The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages..." I'v edited my answer to point to the 3.4 docs as that is what the OP is using.

Comment: I also updated the directory structure to better match the edited question.

Comment: I belive you mean `Setup.py` and not `Septup.py`, emphasizing the capitalization. Is this correct? (I would edit it, but I am unable to do 1 character edits.)

Comment: @lynn you are correct. Thanks for pointing it out. Now fixed.

Answer (score 5):

It is because of `setuptools.find_packages`, when calling it without any parameters it looks for packages in the source tree from the location of `setup.py`. In your case you don't have any folder at the root level.

The issue does not come from your `setup.py` file but from the way you've organized your project, by moving your sources around like so:

```
testSetup
|--setup.py
|--/testSetup/foo.py
|--/testSetup/__init__.py
```

then you can successfully `pip setup.py install` when cd-ing inside `testSetup`.

[some doc on find_packages](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#using-find-packages)

Comment: Sorry, i malformed my question. I have the structured what you describe (i edited my question)

Comment: Waylan found just before you :p

Comment: Yup, just saw that I forgot to include the `__init__.py` ^^